# The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list.

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

Apparently the insert list contains more items than the the number of selected values but cant seem to see where that is the case. by observation they are the same unless I am missing something?

```
   public static DateTime CreateMedicationDispenseLocationHistory( int medicationDispenseID, int locationID, int staffID, DateTime date )
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection( Utilities.DBConnectionString() );
        connection.Open();

        CreateMedicationDispenseLocationHistory( medicationDispenseID, locationID, staffID, date, connection, null );

        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();

        return date;
    }

    public static DateTime CreateMedicationDispenseLocationHistory( int medicationDispenseID, int locationID, int staffID, DateTime date, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction )
    {
        Locations location = new Locations();
        MedicationList medication = new MedicationList();
        StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();

        SqlCommand command;

        sqlString.Append("INSERT INTO [MedicationDispenseLocationHistory] (");
        sqlString.Append("MedicationDispenseID, " );
        sqlString.Append("LocationID, " );
        sqlString.Append("StaffID, " );
        sqlString.Append("DateTimeStamp" );
        sqlString.Append(") SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();");

        command = new SqlCommand( sqlString.ToString(), connection );
        if( ( transaction != null ) ) command.Transaction = transaction;

        command.Parameters.Add( "@MedicationDispenseID", SqlDbType.Int ).Value = medication.MedicationDispenseID;
        command.Parameters.Add( "@LocationID", SqlDbType.Int ).Value = location.LocationID;
        command.Parameters.Add( "@StaffID", SqlDbType.Int, 500 ).Value = Helper.GetValue( GlobalVariables.loggedInStaff.StaffID );
        command.Parameters.Add( "@DateTimeStamp", SqlDbType.DateTime ).Value = Helper.GetDBDateValue(DateTime.Now);
        //command.Parameters.Add("@stopDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Helper.GetValue(medicationDispense.StopDate);
        medication.MedicationDispenseID = Convert.ToInt32( command.ExecuteScalar() );

        return date;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a semicolon at the end of the INSERT INTO statement

```
  sqlString.Append("); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();");
```

Otherwise the following **SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()** will be interpreted as the SELECT list of values for the INSERT

[INSERT INTO ....... SELECT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

To complete the answer (giving credit to the authors of the comments below)
Do not forget to add the values placeholders for your parameters

```
  sqlString.Append(") VALUES (@MedicationDispenseID,@LocationID,@StaffID,@DateTimeStamp);");
  sqlString.Append("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();");
```

Comment: And he should add a VALUES clause to the INSERT that uses the parameters to make it work.

Comment: The insert statement itself still doesn't have tokens/placeholders for the parameter values. Where do they go? If all you do is insert a semi-colon it will be `INSERT dbo.table(col1,col2); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();` - which is not valid either.

Comment: Yes How Could I forget the values!